# Работа с MovieClip во flash professional?

Tags: flash, actionscript, apache-flex

Надо сделать во flash professional рисунок, который будет использован потом в коде (пишу во FlashDevelop).
То есть создаются классы которые я могу использовать (не могу правильно сказать, потому что не работал с  флешем) Насколько я понял создаются отдельные символы, из которых уже создается общая картина.
Подскажите как это сделать ? (Если поняли что мне надо)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объекты из сцены Flash Pro при загрузке в ActionScript 3, в простейшем случае приводятся к классу MovieClip (или Sprite, Shape, Bitmap в зависимости от того во что они конвертировались)

```
  var _object:MovieClip = _swf.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
```

Затем они участвуют в программном потоке, двигаются, включается/выключается анимация и т.д. Поиск нужного мувика можно производить например по имени класса (Задан в Flash Pro)

```
  var s:String = getQualifiedClassName(_object);
  if ( s.indexOf("PLACE_CELL") != -1 )
      {
            var mc:MovieClip = (_object as MovieClip);                  
            mc.buttonMode = true;
            mc.blendMode = BlendMode.ADD;
            mc.alpha = 0.5;
      }
```

Сам проект обычно не видит типов из загруженной флешки, (только строковые именования), хотя доступ к типам есть в Flash Builder 4.5 - Flash Professional Project.

Comment: @ShockWave а как это создавать в flash pro, есть какие нибудь мануалы ? Мне ничего сложного не надо, просто типа карты на которой будут точки, меняющие состояние и они соеденины линиями..

Comment: - Создаете объект (круг).
 - Конвертируете в symbol.
 - В свойствах ставите галочку Export for ActionScript.
 - Задаете имя класса объекта.

Тут несколько примеров.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/concept_export_for_as.html

http://flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/as3link/title=AS3:FlashCS3Workflow

http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/as3link/